# After fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 over 200 packages can be removed with apt autoremove

Tags: apt, 20.04

Linux newcomer here. A few days ago I learned the lesson to **always** make sure to properly read what packages are removed with `apt autoremove` regardless of how tired I am. To make a long story short for some reason I was prompted to remove **a lot** of packages and simply proceeded. As a result, a lot of data was removed including kernel versions and whatnot. I realised that something was wrong about halfway through when I was warned that I was in the process of deleting the currently active kernel. I know, stupid.

After rebooting the grub bootloader didn't have list Ubuntu anymore, so I had to set up a fresh install. I'm using a laptop from Tuxedo Computers, so I was able to use their WebFAI to set up Ubuntu 20.04. Luckily I was able to restore all of my data from a recent backup.

For some reason I am now again prompted to remove over 200 packages using `apt autoremove`. The output is pasted below.

**I'd appreciate it if you could let me know if I can remove these packages safely or if you recognise some of them as important.**

Thank you!

`The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required: appmenu-gtk-module-common appmenu-gtk3-module apport-symptoms apt-clone apt-config-icons-large apt-config-icons-large-hidpi archdetect-deb bluedevil breeze breeze-cursor-theme breeze-gtk-theme catdoc dctrl-tools dpkg-repack drkonqi fonts-hack fonts-noto-hinted fonts-noto-unhinted frameworkintegration gir1.2-timezonemap-1.0 gir1.2-xkl-1.0 ieee-data kaccounts-providers kde-cli-tools kde-cli-tools-data kde-config-gtk-style kde-config-sddm kde-style-breeze kde-style-oxygen-qt5 kdeconnect kdoctools5 kgamma5 khelpcenter khotkeys khotkeys-data kinit kio-extras kio-extras-data kmenuedit kpeople-vcard kscreen ksysguard ksysguard-data ksysguardd ktexteditor-data ktexteditor-katepart kwin-style-breeze kwrited libaccounts-qt5-1 libappmenu-gtk3-parser0 libappstreamqt2 libaribb24-0 libbasicusageenvironment1 libcddb2 libcolorcorrect5 libdebian-installer4 libdmtx0b libdvbpsi10 libebml4v5 libeditorconfig0 libepub0 libfakekey0 libflatpak0 libgit2-28 libgps26 libgrantlee-templates5 libgroupsock8 libhttp-parser2.9 libixml10 libkaccounts1 libkf5activitiesstats1 libkf5baloo5 libkf5balooengine5 libkf5bluezqt-data libkf5bluezqt6 libkf5contacts-data libkf5contacts5 libkf5dnssd-data libkf5dnssd5 libkf5emoticons-bin libkf5emoticons-data libkf5emoticons5 libkf5filemetadata-bin libkf5filemetadata-data libkf5filemetadata3 libkf5holidays-data libkf5holidays5 libkf5itemmodels5 libkf5js5 libkf5kdelibs4support-data libkf5kdelibs4support5 libkf5kdelibs4support5-bin libkf5khtml-bin libkf5khtml-data libkf5khtml5 libkf5networkmanagerqt6 libkf5notifyconfig-data libkf5notifyconfig5 libkf5people-data libkf5people5 libkf5peoplebackend5 libkf5peoplewidgets5 libkf5prison5 libkf5pty-data libkf5pty5 libkf5pulseaudioqt2 libkf5purpose-bin libkf5purpose5 libkf5runner5 libkf5screen-bin libkf5screen7 libkf5style5 libkf5su-bin libkf5su-data libkf5su5 libkf5syntaxhighlighting-data libkf5syntaxhighlighting5 libkf5sysguard-bin libkf5sysguard-data libkf5texteditor-bin libkf5texteditor5 libkf5texteditor5-libjs-underscore libkf5threadweaver5 libkfontinst5 libkfontinstui5 libksgrd7 libksignalplotter7 libkworkspace5-5 liblivemedia77 liblua5.2-0 libmad0 libmarkdown2 libmatroska6v5 libmbedcrypto3 libmbedtls12 libmbedx509-0 libnotificationmanager1 libopenmpt-modplug1 liboxygenstyle5-5 liboxygenstyleconfig5-5 libpackagekitqt5-1 libpam-kwallet-common libpam-kwallet5 libphonon4qt5-4 libphonon4qt5-data libplacebo7 libplasma-geolocation-interface5 libpoppler-qt5-1 libpowerdevilcore2 libpowerdevilui5 libprocesscore7 libprocessui7 libproxy-tools libqalculate20 libqalculate20-data libqca-qt5-2 libqca-qt5-2-plugins libqrencode4 libqt5webkit5 libresid-builder0c2a libscim8v5 libsdl-image1.2 libsidplay2 libsignon-plugins-common1 libsignon-qt5-1 libsnapd-qt1 libspatialaudio0 libssh2-1 libtaskmanager6 libtimezonemap-data libtimezonemap1 libupnp13 libusageenvironment3 libvlc-bin libvlc5 libvlccore9 libweather-ion7 libxcb-dpms0 libxcb-record0 libzip5 milou oxygen-sounds phonon4qt5 phonon4qt5-backend-vlc plasma-browser-integration plasma-desktop-data plasma-discover plasma-discover-backend-fwupd plasma-discover-backend-snap plasma-discover-common plasma-integration plasma-pa plasma-thunderbolt powerdevil powerdevil-data python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5 python3-icu python3-pam python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit python3-systemd qdbus-qt5 qml-module-org-kde-activities qml-module-org-kde-bluezqt qml-module-org-kde-draganddrop qml-module-org-kde-kcm qml-module-org-kde-kcoreaddons qml-module-org-kde-kholidays qml-module-org-kde-kio qml-module-org-kde-kwindowsystem qml-module-org-kde-people qml-module-org-kde-purpose qml-module-org-kde-qqc2desktopstyle qml-module-org-kde-quickcharts qml-module-org-kde-runnermodel qml-module-org-kde-solid qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel qml-module-qt-labs-settings qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts qtchooser rdate signon-plugin-oauth2 socat software-properties-qt sshfs systemsettings user-manager vlc-data vlc-plugin-base vlc-plugin-video-output xsettingsd Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.`